# Word Form to Excel via VBA takes forever

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a Word form with about 150 fillable elements. I am importing this form into Excel with the following code, after selecting the file in VBA as myDoc:

```
With myDoc
    For Each CCtl In .ContentControls
        i = i + 1
        j = 1
        Tags = Split(CCtl.Tag, ";")
        For x = 0 To UBound(Tags)
            myWkSht.Cells(i, j + x) = Tags(x)
        Next x
        myWkSht.Cells(i, j + 5) = CCtl.Range.Text
        myWkSht.Cells(i, j + 6) = BieterID
    Next
    myWkSht.Columns.AutoFit
End With
```

The Code does what it's supposed to do, however the Macro takes more than half an hour to finish. Does anyone know how to optimize the run-time here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

It first reads the data into an array - without splitting the tag!
Then this array is written to the Excel sheet.

Depending on your Excel version you can use `TEXTSPLIT`formula or do the splitting row by row.

I would think that this is much faster than your solution.

```vb
Dim arrValues As Variant, i As Long
ReDim arrValues(1 To myDoc.ContentControls.Count, 1 To 3)

Dim cc As ContentControl
For Each cc In myDoc.ContentControls
    i = i + 1
    arrValues(i, 1) = BieterID
    arrValues(i, 2) = cc.Range.Text
    arrValues(i, 3) = cc.Tag
Next


Dim rgFormula As Range
Dim arrSplit As Variant

With myWkSht
    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arrValues, 1), UBound(arrValues, 2)).Value = arrValues
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrValues, 1)
    
'  Solution for Excel 365 current channel
'        With .Cells(i, 4)
'            .Formula2R1C1 = "=TEXTSPLIT(RC[-1],"";"")"
'            .SpillingToRange.Value = .SpillingToRange.Value
'        End With
        
'Solution for all other Excel versions
        arrSplit = Split(.Cells(i, 3), ";")
        .Cells(i, 4).Resize(, UBound(arrSplit) + 1) = arrSplit
    Next
    
    .Columns(3).Delete xlShiftToLeft
End With
```